# Debug randomly acting slow in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Yesterday i had worked on this solution and ran it with debugging enabled perfectly well on two systems yesterday, and today i tried debugging it and it took about 15 minutes for the window to even appear. I didn't change any settings, change any code, etc. Ran it with the exact same build as the day before, on a different system yes, but both systems ran the code perfectly fine yesterday. Now they take an extremely long time to even start and once finally started it is unusably slow in debugging mode. Note, this doesn't happen when i disable debugging. I've tried multiple things, such as cleaning, rebuilding, deleting .suo files, and more. I am wondering how to fix this problem which i think primarily has to do with visual studio's debugger, my project, or my solution, as this doesn't happen with any other projects.

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and this slow debugging is only the case for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out accidentally when changing the 'enable native debugging' setting on. Having it on was making the debugger load a lot of .pdb files that i didn't need.